# android -java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification with Adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

I get this error on different version of android and different devices .I've test it on several devices my self and didn't get this problems but on some devices it keeps showing me this error

this is the ListAdapter code :

```
ListAdapter ladap;

private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { 
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        Spots_tab1_json sh = new Spots_tab1_json();
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url + page, Spots_tab1_json.GET);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = new String(c.getString("id").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                    String dates = new String(c.getString("dates").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                    String price = new String(c.getString("gheymat").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    contact.put("id", id);
                    contact.put("dates", dates);
                    contact.put("price", price);
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                goterr = true;
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                goterr = true;
            }
        } else {
            goterr = true;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (!isCancelled() && goterr == false) {
            if(ladap==null){
                ladap=new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList);
                lv.setAdapter(ladap);
            }else{
                ladap.addAll(contactList);
            }
    }
}


public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Activity activity;
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;

    public ListAdapter(Activity activity,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
        super();
        this.activity = (Activity) activity;
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void addAll(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList) {
        this.list = contactList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return contactList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return contactList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView title,price;
        ImageView img ; 
        //RelativeLayout rl; 
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

            item = contactList.get(position);
            holder.price.setText(item.get("price"));
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

in the above code, when it comes to onpostExcecute() , it checks if ladab is null ,if it null it comes in and make  the ListAdapter (I've logged and it only comes in once ) and after that , it comes to addAll method and add new items to Adapter .

this is the log :

```
STACK_TRACE = java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131034188, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class xx.xx.MainActivity$ListAdapter)]
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1517)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1925)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7462)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:962)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7462)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1268)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1140)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1057)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7462)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7462)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:743)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7462)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1268)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1140)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1057)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7462)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7462)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1268)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1140)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1057)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7462)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7462)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7462)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1140)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3694)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What is the problem of this code ? I've done everything I could but I didn't manage to solve it .

could you help me /

thank you

Answer (score 1):

I got a little bit confuse on your code here :

```
    if (!isCancelled() && goterr == false) {
        if(ladap==null){
            ladap=new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList);
            lv.setAdapter(ladap);
        }else{
            ladap.addAll(contactList);
        }
}
```

Lets say, the code run for the 1st time, where :

`isCancelled()` is false

`goterr` is false

`ladap` will be null, because it has not been created.

If those 3 happened,  `ladap.addAll(contactList);` will **not** be called because  `if(ladap==null)` is `true`.

Try to make it like this :

```
    if (!isCancelled() && goterr == false) {
        if(ladap==null){
            ladap=new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList);
            lv.setAdapter(ladap);
        }
        ladap.addAll(contactList); //no neet for else

}
```

**UPDATE**

Try this :

```
    if (!isCancelled() && goterr == false) {
        if(ladap==null){
            ladap=new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList);
            lv.setAdapter(ladap);
        }
        ladap.addAll(contactList); //no neet for else
        lv.invalidateViews();
        //lv.invalidate(); //try to call this if invalidateViews is not working, do some trial - error here
}
```

Or, you can just move `ladap=new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList);` and set its `adapter` to the `onCreate`.

Comment: thanks for the reply , I still have the problem . i did what you said but it didn't solve my problem . What do you think is the problem ? any guess ? Thanks

Comment: @johnsmoth hmm..its strange. Please see my updated answer and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your code of the `onPostExecute` method into `runOnUiThread`:

```
if (!isCancelled() && goterr == false) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(ladap==null){
                ladap=new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList);
                lv.setAdapter(ladap);
            }else{
                ladap.addAll(contactList);
            }
        }
    });
}
```